# Delete everything after second underscore

Tags: text-processing, command-line, bioinformatics

I want to delete all the text after the second underscore (including the underscore itself), but not on every line. Every of the target lines begin with a pattern (>gi_).

EXAMPLE.

**Input**

`>gi_12_pork_cat`

`ACGT`

`>gi_34_pink_blue`

`CGTA`

**Output**

`>gi_12`

`ACGT`

`>gi_34`

`CGTA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F_ 'BEGIN {OFS="_"} /^>gi/ {print $1,$2} ! /^>gi/ {print}' input
>gi_12
ACGT
>gi_34
CGTA
```

Comment: Golfing: `awk -F_ 'BEGIN {OFS="_"} /^>gi/ {print $1,$2;next}1' input`

Answer (score 4):

for the lazy among us:

```
cut -d_ -f1,2 input
```

gives us:

```
bash-[514]$ cat input
>gi_12_pork_cat   
ACGT
>gi_34_pink_blue    
CGTA

bash-[515]$ cut -d_ -f1,2 input
>gi_12
ACGT    
>gi_34
CGTA
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a short hand using `awk`:

```
awk -F_ '{print $1 (NF>1? FS $2 : "")}' yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ne '/^>gi_/s/_/\n/2;P' yourfile
```

---

### Explanation

- Only for lines that begin with the string `>gi_` are we to try to effect the sub `_ ---> \n`. Then we print the pattern space using the `P` command which prints upto the first newline if it finds one or the whole of it.